# CSS How to change background color of text?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have just 3 words on my webpage that I want to have colored background: Red, Green and Blue. There are 2 components to my questions:

1. How should I do this? Put this in a style sheet or just hard code it in the webpage?
2. Either way, please show me how to do what I want each way so I can decide. I am an absolute beginner with css as you can tell.

BTW, I am doing this in an aspx page if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put each word in a tag, and give each tag a background color.

Something like this:

```
<span style="background-color: red;">Word 1</span>
<span style="background-color: green;">Word 2</span>
<span style="background-color: blue;">Word 3</span>
```

Comment: You can put each in a class if you wanted, sure in css file will be better, but I wrote it inline just for the demo.

Answer (score 4):

For inline styles:

```
<span style="background-color:red;">Red Stuff...</span>
<span style="background-color:green;">Green Stuff...</span>
<span style="background-color:blue;">Blue Stuff...</span>
```

For Css File

```
.red{
  background-color: red;
}

.green{
  background-color: green;
}

.blue{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

and in your html;

```
<span class="red">red stuff</span>
<span class="green">green stuff</span>
<span class="blue">blue stuff</span>
```

The choice should depend whether you want to use these properties on other places. If so go with a style sheet. (IMHO go with a seperate style sheet anyway)

Answer (score 2):

Method 1

HTML

```
    <div>
     <p id="red">Red</p>
     <p id="green">Green</p>
     <p id="blue">Blue</p>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    p#red
    {
    background-color: red;
    }

   p#green
    {
    background-color: green;
    }

   p#blue
    {
    background-color: blue;
    }
```

Method 2

HTML

```
<p><span>Red</span><span>Green</span><span>Blue</span></p>
```

CSS

```
   p>span:nth-child(1)
   {
   background-color: red;
   }

   p>span:nth-child(2)
   {
   background-color: green;
   }

   p>span:nth-child(3)
   {
   background-color: blue;
   }
```

Add this in you HTML inside the head

```
<link rel="stylsheet" type="text/css" href="#foo" />
```

Name you stylesheet CSS file and put the relative/absolute path in the above href

Comment: It is ASP.NET. Someone may use an old version of IE. The `nth-child` is too new.

Comment: @Michas: Thanks. Should have included that as a side comment for method 2. Method 1 is there as fallback.

Comment: Use the Hexadecimal values instead of color names.

Answer (score 2):

Can anyone tell me how to add syntax coloration to my post so I can add an answer to this question.I'll tell how to generate that code with c#.

So the code is :

```
string[] cols = { "red","green","blue"} // or any other color
string[] words = { "","","" } // Put your words inside quotes
string res = "";
for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++) 
{
    res+= "<span style=" + "\" + "background-color:" 
    + cols[i] + "\" + " >" + words[i] +  "</span>";
} 
// the code till now should either be in script tags
// or in the code file linked with your web page
// If you are using visual studio that is the name of the pate.aspx.cs
// now use in the aspx page
<% Response.Write(res); %> // I am not sure if the semicolon is required here.
```

This is if you want to do it on the server side.

Comment: Hit space 4 times before each line of code. And have an empty line before your code block.

Comment: The code is right I don't know why it got bad syntax coloration.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest putting that in style sheet. I personally like to avoid having any "hard css" (not sure about the right word).

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
span.textRed
{
background-color: red;
}
span.textGreen
{
background-color: green;
}
span.textBlue
{
background-color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<span class="textRed"> Red </span>
<span class="textGreen"> Red </span>
<span class="textBlue"> Red </span>
</body>
```